# Can Camping handle rollbacks?

Tags: migration, camping

I wrote a migration and migrated to it (on a dev copy, of course) before realizing I forgot to initialize a value, then puzzled for the next ten minutes over how Camping might make it possible to rollback. I realize I can just [write another migration to fix the data](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html), which is what I intend to do, but it begs the question:

**Can I rollback a migration in Camping**, or do I have to rely on writing an X.1 any time I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell `App.create_schema` what version to migrate to:

```
Camping.goes :App

…

App.create_schema(:version => 1.1)
```

Note that you'll have to define down-migrations (or use change-migrations) for this to work.